# Justify big text in a button option

Tags: html, css, button, text, justify

I am trying to build a quiz and when I am not being able to justify it all the way, look at my [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/matheusloures/py80qq8q/).

HTML

```
            <div id="1" class="option"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam nec dolor nisi. Sed dui lacus, placerat eget hendrerit ut, pellentesque ut arcu. Suspendisse sagittis nisi sapien, vitae porta odio gravida eu.</p></div>
            <div id="2" class="option"><p>Suspendisse suscipit velit a enim porta ultricies. Vivamus sit amet purus in sapien euismod congue eu at felis. Nulla vehicula rutrum elit, et congue libero cursus at. Phasellus eu nisi nec mi volutpat eleifend. Curabitur sollicitudin laoreet augue vitae egestas</p></div>
            <div id="3" class="option"><p>Duis ut ante elit. Vestibulum varius et tellus ac condimentum. Nam scelerisque faucibus massa, sed molestie mauris convallis et. Duis luctus lobortis quam et varius.</p></div>
```

CSS

```
                .option{width:400px;
                height:200px;
                margin:15px;
                font-size:18px;
                color:#FFFFFF; 
                padding:2px;
                padding-left:10px;
                border: 2px solid white;
                cursor:pointer;
                background-color:#3399FF;
                line-height: 200px;
                text-align: center;
                white-space: normal;
                }

                .option:hover{
                border:#FC0 solid 2px;
                color:#FC0;
                }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have `text-align: center;`, so how do you expect it to `justify`?

Comment: Line-height set to 200px is too not good way to get your effect

Comment: Cool! Thanks @Dekel . There is any way the button follows the size of the text? For example, for "Hello, my name is Stack", the button comes smaller. For "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sceleris que odio ac eros posuere ultrices. Vestibulum posuere neque vitae diam iaculis hendrerit. Donec cursus facilisis tortor at volutpat." the button comes bigger.

Comment: Hey @KrzysztofKrólikowski That shouldn't be there. Thanks! There is any way the button follows the size of the text? For example, for "Hello, my name is Stack", the button comes smaller. For "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sceleris que odio ac eros posuere ultrices. Vestibulum posuere neque vitae diam iaculis hendrerit. Donec cursus facilisis tortor at volutpat." the button comes bigger.

Comment: Why do you use `div` if you need a `button`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put off from your style height, line-height and set text-align to justify:

```
     .option{width:400px;
            margin:15px;
            font-size:18px;
            color:#FFFFFF; 
            padding:2px;
            padding-left:10px;
            border: 2px solid white;
            cursor:pointer;
            background-color:#3399FF;
            text-align: justify;
            white-space: normal;
            }

            .option:hover{
            border:#FC0 solid 2px;
            color:#FC0;
            }
```